# How to fetch specific value first then ascending order using Laravel Elequent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

How to fetch specific value first then ascending order using Laravel Eloquent?

I want to show `India` first then other countries in ascending. I am using

```
$country_data= country::orderBy('country_id','India')->get();
```

Comment: for get only one model use **->first()** instead of **->get()**

Comment: maybe you want like this **$country = Country::orderBy('country_id')->where('name', 'India')->first();**

Comment: I want to fetch complete list of all countries , but want to show India at first place, after india,all country in assecding order

Comment: you have name field in db??

Comment: $country_data= country::orderBy('country_name','India')->get();

Comment: How you save your info in dabtabase. which fields is has your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user `orderByRaw` with `mySQL` `FIELD` function

So try this:

`$country_data= country::orderByRaw("FIELD(country_id,'India') DESC")->orderBy("country_id","asc")->get();`